# twilio api for choosing between different calling plans

Tags: twilio

I need to choose between different plans like the following "For unlimited calling press 1, for 100 minutes press 2"
Need to make it done by Twilio API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I would suggest looking at the Twilio documentation which can be found at:
https://www.twilio.com/docs

Secondly, They provide various example applications which can be found here:
https://www.twilio.com/docs/howto

You wouldn't actually do this via their API though - you'd use TWIML (Twilio Markup Language). To get you started... (I'm going to write this in PHP and TWIML)

Create a page called index.php and add the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Gather action="gather.php" method="GET">
        <Say>
            For unlimited calling press 1, for 100 minutes press 2
        </Say>
    </Gather>
    <Say>We didn't receive any input. Goodbye!</Say>
</Response>
```

Create another page called gather.php. On this page you would have:

```
<?php

$response = $_REQUEST['Digits'];

if($response == 1){
    $message = 'You pressed 1 for unlimited calling.';
}elseif($response == 2){
    $message = 'You pressed 2 for 100 minutes';
}

echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n";
echo "<Response><Say>You entered " . $response . "</Say></Response>";
?>
```

Obviously, on the gather.php page you would need to write the appropriate code to process what the calling party had selected.